# SRAM X4 MTB Rear Derailleur H-Limit screw maximum open, but still on 7th Cog?

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur-rear, sram

I own a 6 months old Rockrider 5.2 mountain bike.

Everything was great until recently I noticed that the Rear Derailleur of my bike doesn't reach the highest gear cog, which is 8th. Its always stuck on 7th.

I tried opening the H-Limit screw completely and it even came off, but my chain doesn't still move to the highest cog.

I have a beautiful Sunday morning ride planned in 6 hours from now. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you move it by hand so that the chain catches on the 8th cog?  Obviously be careful when doing that, but is it the range of motion that's limited or the range the cable is managing to pull it?

Comment: The range was limited. I tried moving it but it did not. But, interestingly when I loosened the L-Limit screw it moved. I was surprised. I thought you first adjust the H-Limit screw and then go to the L-Limit screw. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is if your rear derailleur is bent. If that is not the case, check the cable tension is not too high. Is the shifter acting funny (like hard to shift)?

See this link to see how to do adjustments: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailler-adjustments-derailleur

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I tried all of them. Tried all the basic procedure. It turns out it was the L-limit screw that was preventing the cog from moving to 8th gear. :-O After I loosened the L-limit screw and I performed the tuning procedure, everything went fine. \m/

Answer (score 1):

You'll net to release the cable anchor on the derailleur. Place the shifter in the 8th position. Turn the cranks and the chain should shift the the highest gear. Reset the high limit screw. Pull the cable snug and tighten cable anchor. You will likely need to fine tune with the cable adjuster.

Comment: The cable was out. I released the cable and it was hanging and wasn't anchored at all. After a little research I figured that undoing the L-Limit screw actually helped. It allowed the cog to move to the 8th gear. I am not sure why.